# Adding MouseListener to Netbeans TopComponent

Tags: java, swing, treeview, netbeans-8, netbeans-platform

```
public final class DataSetTopComponent extends TopComponent implements ExplorerManager.Provider, DatabaseManagerListener, GroupViewUIListener, MouseListener{

  public DataSetTopComponent() {
         addMouseListener(this);
  }

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    System.out.println("Mosue Clicked");
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    System.out.println("Mosue Pressed");
    // //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    //  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}}
```

I want to listen mosue action in this final TopComponent class but it does not work.Can someone help me ?

**Not: TopComponent class come from org.openide.windows.TopComponent**

Comment: The code is correct, it should work. So the problem comes from the code you're not showing. How this TopComponent is integrated in the UI ? Did you use the Netbeans wizard to add the TopComponent (recommended) ?

Comment: I have a component as TreeView treeView = new BeanTreeView(); I try to take double click on this treeview.                                                                                                               the class imported:                                                                                             
import org.openide.explorer.view.BeanTreeView;
import org.openide.explorer.view.TreeView;